# Electron dialog.showOpenDialog() closes app on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, dialog, electron

I am trying to use Electron dialog.showOpenDialog() on Ubuntu 18.10, but the method - when used - closes the electron-based app immediately.

Simple usage of dialog.showOpenDialog() results in app crash. When I comment it out, the app works fine. When I use the same code on Windows, it works.

Does anyone here have some tips how to change the code specifically for Ubuntu?

I've tried to use the method in both main and renderer processes with no luck. 
The native dialog opens for a moment and then the whole app quits.

In the main process:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
...
dialog.showOpenDialog(
    {
      title: "Select a file",
      filters: [{ name: "All Files", extensions: ["*"] }]
    },
    fileNames => {     
      if (fileNames === undefined) {
        console.log("No file selected");        
      }
      ...
})
...
```

**Edit**: I've tried a very simple example:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require('electron');


// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}


// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  //if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
ipcMain.on('openFile', (event, path) => {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(function (fileNames) {
    // fileNames is an array that contains all the selected 
    if (fileNames === undefined) {
      console.log("No file selected");
    } else {
      console.log("fileNames", fileNames);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: can you paste the entire main process code?

Comment: I would try commenting out the `filters` line, just for a reality check.

Comment: Which Electron version are you using? I.e. what's the output of `npm list electron` ?

Comment: Thanks. @Sharvink, another sample added to the question. The app still closes immediately.

Comment: @NoGrabbing - I've tried various options, but the result is still the same.

Comment: @snwflk - I used electron 2.0.9 and 5.0.2. Ubuntu 18.10 is virtualized (virtualBox, user account osboxes.org).

Comment: maybe check the issues reported on the Electron github repository. I would be surprised if an error that obvious has not been reported.

Comment: @NoGrabbing thanks. You are right. There are issues related to electron and ubuntu 18.10 reported on the github repo. Next time I'll start there.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the default Ubuntu terminal to run the electron app. I was using the VS Code terminal and turns out it had an issue according to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20380)